# Unity (Vuforia) embedded within Android App

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

i have the exact same problem here with the different that

- when i added vuforia wrapper unity application got crashed before lunching
- if i didn't add vuforia wrapper the unity app open and behave normally but with black screen instead of camera

[Unity (Vuforia) project integrated in Android project shows a black screen on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646956/unity-vuforia-project-integrated-in-android-project-shows-a-black-screen-on-st?fbclid=IwAR1DKqG5I_bK95DKhPJJTQNOpFP87dUIwSG5L7RCCVTsJGasPnC9sJ7Nz8k)

Unity Version: 2018.3.6f1

Vuforia version: 8.1.7

Android APP Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfit"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation(name: 'DressAR-debug', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'VuforiaWrapper', ext:'aar')
}
```

Unity APP Gradle

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'VuforiaWrapper', ext:'aar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb']
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/x86/*.so'
    }

}
```

Comment: Show your code. Which version of Unity and Android SDK are you using? Show some work please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity (Vuforia) project integrated in Android project shows a black screen on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646956/unity-vuforia-project-integrated-in-android-project-shows-a-black-screen-on-st)

Comment: done edit, added more information

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with you I have searched for a lot of tutorials and I found this post and it worked on my project, good luck

[No implementation found for void com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRestartActivityIndicator()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959096/no-implementation-found-for-void-com-unity3d-player-unityplayer-nativerestartact)

1. Open Unity Build Setting
2. In android player settings change "scripting backend" to IL2CPP.
3. In android player settings mark ARM64 checkbox as selected.
4. Then export again.